# Tela preta no loop do EMBED do youtube

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, iframe

Coloquei um vídeo de background na tela de login da minha pagina porem quando o vídeo chega ao fim ele fica com a tela preta por 3 segundos até recomeçar o vídeo como faço para que ele faça isso instantaneamente ?

HTML

```
  <div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
      <iframe 
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ng8Wivt52K0?controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=ng8Wivt52K0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.video-background {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
  }
  .video-foreground,
  .video-background iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  #vidtop-content {
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.vid-info { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 33%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: #fff; padding: 1rem; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.vid-info h1 { font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 700; margin-top: 0; line-height: 1.2; }
.vid-info a { display: block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); transition: .6s background; border-bottom: none; margin: 1rem auto; text-align: center; }
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
.vid-info { width: 50%; padding: .5rem; }
.vid-info h1 { margin-bottom: .2rem; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.vid-info .acronym { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa "tela preta" a que se refere é o *delay* de quando o vídeo termina e reinicia. Por vias normais isso não tem como ser evitado. No entanto você pode usar uma forma que substitui o vídeo quando ele está terminando por outro já iniciado (no caso, o mesmo vídeo), dando ideia de continuidade e evitando a tela preta.

Quando vídeo estiver em 27 segundos (do total de 30), o script injetará na `div` um novo vídeo com `z-index: -1` que fará com que ele fique por baixo do atual e já inicie. Usando `setTimeout`, após de 3 segundos, o vídeo que está terminando será excluído da página e o que estava abaixo ficará visível.

Se você acha a tela preta um incômodo e não tiver problema de um `setInterval` sendo executado em *background*, segue o script:

```
window.onload = function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      var vclone = document.createElement("iframe");
      vclone.setAttribute("style","z-index:-1;");
      vclone.setAttribute("frameborder","0");
      vclone.setAttribute("allowfullscreen","");
      vclone.src = document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].getAttribute("src");
      var container = document.querySelector(".video-foreground");
      container.appendChild(vclone);

      setTimeout(function(){
         document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[1].style.zIndex = "0";
         document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].outerHTML = "";
      }, 3000);

   }, 27000);
}
```